# Does the number of columns updated affect the performance of update query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I have an Oracle update query like below

Query1 : `UPDATE Table1 set col1=value1 where tablekey=123`

Query2 : `UPDATE Table1 set col1=value1,col2=value2 where tablekey=123`

Will there be a performance difference between these two?

Comment: Assuming no triggers involved, I wouldn't worry. (As long as normal size columns.)

Comment: Create a test case and you will find out. Performance depends greatly on your setup (HW, init parameters, indexes, etc.). Comparison is meaningless because they are not functionally equivalent. Comparing three separate column updates and one statement updating three columns is.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing much, except the **number of bytes**.

You could check the **EXPLAIN PLAN**:

```
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR UPDATE EMP SET ENAME='A' WHERE EMPNO=7369;

Explained.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1494045816

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | UPDATE STATEMENT   |      |     1 |    10 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  UPDATE            | EMP  |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |     1 |    10 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("EMPNO"=7369)

14 rows selected.

SQL>
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR UPDATE EMP SET ENAME='A', DEPTNO=30 WHERE EMPNO=7369;

Explained.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1494045816

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | UPDATE STATEMENT   |      |     1 |    13 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  UPDATE            | EMP  |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |     1 |    13 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("EMPNO"=7369)

14 rows selected.
```

For more detailed information, you could **set autotrace on**:

```
SQL> set autotrace on
SQL> UPDATE EMP SET ENAME='A' WHERE EMPNO=7369;

1 row updated.


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1494045816

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | UPDATE STATEMENT   |      |     1 |    10 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  UPDATE            | EMP  |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |     1 |    10 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("EMPNO"=7369)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          4  recursive calls
          1  db block gets
          3  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
        352  redo size
        857  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        842  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          3  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          2  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          1  rows processed

SQL> UPDATE EMP SET ENAME='A', DEPTNO=30 WHERE EMPNO=7369;

1 row updated.


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1494045816

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | UPDATE STATEMENT   |      |     1 |    13 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  UPDATE            | EMP  |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |     1 |    13 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("EMPNO"=7369)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          4  recursive calls
          1  db block gets
          3  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
        316  redo size
        858  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        853  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          3  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          2  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          1  rows processed

SQL>
```

So, you see a very slight difference for the **`bytes sent via SQL*Net to client`** and **`bytes received via SQL*Net from client`**. For more columns, the difference would increase slightly more.

Answer (score 1):

In this examples, tables TT1 and TT2 both have same data in first update I'm updating only 1 column and in other update I'm updating 3 columns, (both tables don't have any triggers). The timings as you can see pretty much the same.

*The table contains just mock data.

```
SQL> UPDATE TT1 SET EMPNO=1234 WHERE EMPNO=7839 ;

65536 rows updated.

Elapsed: 00:00:06.65

SQL> UPDATE TT2 SET EMPNO=1234,SAL=1000,DEPTNO=15 WHERE EMPNO=7839 ;

65536 rows updated.

Elapsed: 00:00:05.76
SQL>
```

Comment: Just a piece of info, if you gather the statistics after the first update, the second update might be closer w.r.t to time taken. Having said that, the new statistics are required only on the average row length.

Answer (score 0):

put below query on top of your update query,it will gives you time required for execution of queries and SQL Server parse and compile time.

> SET STATISTICS TIME ON